# How to handle json type request and xml type request using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

Some times I will get request as json(from rest client) format and some times xml(from form using jsp view) format. When i am written controller class as shown below, it will not allow request xml(from form using jsp view).

This is my problem. Controller class should allow both type of request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getCustomer(@RequestBody HomeRequest homeRequestequest,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

        String response = homeService.getCustomerResponse(homeRequestequest, request);
         return response;
        }
```

Please help how to resolve this issue. I am using 3.2.4.RELEASE version.

Comment: What's the `annotation` on the controller `@RestController` or `@Controller`?

Comment: I am using @controller

Comment: What do you mean by "not allow"?

Comment: request or response?!!! getCustomer() should return xml/json response  or request is xml/json !!!! put proper description.

Comment: Request and Response both

Comment: "not allow" means it is giving exception..

Comment: If the request must accept a POST from a form and from a Json body your Controller method must accept `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json`. You might want to try the `consumes` in the RequestMapping annotation but ultimately I think you should declare two methods that share same business logic.

Answer (score 0):

As jbarrueta said in comments, you need to declare 2 methods in Controller, e.g.

`getCustomerJson` and `getCustomerXML`.

The mappping for the first method would be :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
```

and the mapping for the second method would be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/xml")
```

Comment: We should write 2 methods...? I there any solution other than writing two methods